# How do I stream videos from web server in Silverlight using ExpressionMediaPlayer control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend, mediaelement

I would like to stream videos that reside at the webserver from within a ExpressionMediaPlayer control. The following results in a network error. I believe that the problem is with my Uri. I have the videos inside the 'ClentBin' folder. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

```
private void videoList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             var selectedVideo = (Video)videoList.SelectedItem;        
             PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem();
            item.MediaSource = new Uri(@"/ClientBin/" + selectedVideo.FilePath,         UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            item.IsAdaptiveStreaming = false;
            ep.Playlist.Items.Add(item);
         }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There can be a number of factors that contribute to a network error in the Expression Media Player. Here are some basic checks...

**1. Check the video file itself**
Launch Windows Media Player, go to File > Open URL... and make sure you can play the video with the absolute URL, just to rule out any basic problems with the web server. *(Note that this does not apply if you are working with Adaptive Streaming, which it doesn't appear you are.)*

**2. What does `selectedVideo.FilePath` contain?**
Is this a simple file name (i.e. `MyVideo.wmv`) or is it a relative file path? Forward or backward slashes?

**3. Try it with an absolute static URI**
Just to rule out relative path issues with your app / web server / any virtual directory configuration, try:

```
item.MediaSource = new Uri(@"http://mysite.com/ClientBin/MyVideo.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);
```

**4. Remove the leading slash from /ClientBin/**
Try just `new Uri(@"ClientBin/" + selectedVideo.FilePath, UriKind.Relative);` and see if the relative path is then correct.